# How can I do UI Test automation for the UWP project of my Xamarin application

Tags: xamarin.uwp, gui-testing

As the question says, I have a Xamarin forms application that targets Android, iOS and UWP. I am able to use Xamarin.UITests for UI testing on the Android and iOS project, but I need a frame work to help with UI testing on UWP. I found [this](https://blog.infernored.com/cross-platform-ui-testing-with-specflow-xamarin-and-codedui/) and while it looks helpful, its quite hard to understand, it seems old, so not sure if all of it is still up to date, and the third step in the process is missing (page is 404).

I've also heard of WebDriver, but cannot find any straight forward documentation for how to use it for Xamarin.UWP.

Any ideas on how I can test for UWP?

Answer (score 0):

after i research, I found this method that you can try

this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-windows-store-apps?view=vs-2022

Comment: I'm looking for UI Tests, this article relates to Unit testing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/xamarin-forms?tabs=windows